# Is there a collection of Economics PhD prelims questions?

Tags: reference-request

Out of curiosity, do you know if there is a collection of Economics PhD prelims questions?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Econ.SE. This question as is shows very little effort and is a little confusing. What topic (micro, macro, quant, etc.) are you looking for? At what difficulty? Usually upperclassmen at your institution will be willing to provide past years exams, which seems like it would be more relevant for you.

Comment: I have a personal collection. Will sell. :P

Comment: @123 I have another one. I sell it at $p_{123}-\epsilon$, $\epsilon \in (0,p_{123})$.

Comment: *sigh* I guess we skip the race to the bottom and just make them free :) . I will post mine once I have a bit more free time.

Comment: @123 Beware of copyright infringement though.

Answer (score 7):

Exams from:

- [Harvard](https://economics.harvard.edu/pages/past-general-exams)
- [UC Davis](http://economics.ucdavis.edu/graduate-program/current-students/past-preliminary-exams/prelims)
- [MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/) (only problem sets; go to graduates).

Although more cumbersome, you can also google something like "advanced macroeconomics exams pdf" or so, and you can discover personal pages of lecturers/professors that put up previous exams (or problem sets). For example, resources from a lecturer at [Leipzig](https://www.wifa.uni-leipzig.de/itvwl/makro/lehre/ss2017/am-ex2.html) (go to bottom of page), [Oslo](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON5300/), [Dublin](http://karlwhelan.com/blog/?p=761) (one exam only), [Helsinski](http://www.helsinki.fi/~ajripatt/opetus/index.html).